# How to add up variables of different hosts in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a situation similar to the following:

```yaml
all:
  hosts:
    host1:
      num: 3

    host2:
      num: 4

    host3:
      num: 2
```

I want to template a file to the hosts which should aggregate the value `num` step by step on each of the hosts starting at 1.

So e.g. for host1, the content of a new variable/file `from` should be `1`, for host2 it should be `4` (1+3), and for host3 `8` (4+4). But the order of execution does not really matter - it could also be: host3 `1`, host1 `3` (1+2), host2 `6` (3+3). So the variable `num` basically states how many items the host will handle, and the goal of my question is to give each of the hosts a dedicated number range which would be `[from,from+num-1]`.

EDIT: I have further thought about it, and this could also be precalculated. Basically I want to get from [3,4,2] to [0,3,7](or [1,4,8]). I unfortunately cannot find a Jinja2 Filter that does this.

Comment: Maybe you can use fact delegation for that https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegating-facts

Comment: see [`set_stats`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_stats_module.html)

Comment: I do not know how to obtain the list of hosts ordered by [Ordering execution based on inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#ordering-execution-based-on-inventory). I'm afraid it's not possible. If so, your problem can't be solved. You can create a list or dictionary with the incremented values, of course. But, you'll be never sure about the order of the hosts.

Comment: @VladimirBotka actually it's not really about the order of execution, it can just be any order that the hosts agree on. So this could also be precalculated on the controller machine. Basically i just want to reduce/map an array [a,b,c] to [1, a+1, a+b+1].

Comment: In this case, you might want to "reduce" the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: **"*reduce/map an array [a,b,c] to [1, a+1, a+b+1]*"**

A: [map](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.map) doesn't apply filters additively. An iteration is needed, I'm afraid. For example, given the list

```yaml
l: [10, 20, 30]
```

create the items and concatenate the new list

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        l2: "{{ l2|d([]) + [l[0:(item)]|sum + 1] }}"
      loop: "{{ range(0, l|length) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  l2:
  - 1
  - 11
  - 31
```

Of course, you can write a filter if you want to reduce the list in one step.

Comment: Thank you so much! As an Ansible/Jinja2-Beginner it probably would have taken me hours to come up with this solution... I did not "reduce" my question to only this because I also wanted to include the aspect of using the result on my seperate hosts, which I am also struggling with. Can you maybe point me in the direction I need to go here? Maybe I can start with a Map-like Object [{1.1.1.1: 10}, {2.2.2.2: 20}, {3.3.3.3: 30}] and just transform this to [{1.1.1.1: 1}, {2.2.2.2: 11}, {3.3.3.3: 31}] as we did with the list. Then I thought i could access the value for each host.